# Integrating YAF 1.9.5.5 with Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles, yetanotherforum, yaf

I have a problem with integrating YAF 1.9.5.5 to azure 'web role'.

I successfully added forum to my page and configured config as recommended.

```
  <%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"%>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="YAF" Assembly="YAF" Namespace="YAF" %>

<asp:Content ID="SupportTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Support
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="SupportContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<YAF:Forum runat="server" ID="forum" BoardID="1" />
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

When I run 'web role' the forum successfully displayed, but all actions is not working.
For example when I click "collapsible , new topic, post response" buttons I have no result, just refreshes page

Can anyone help me with this??

Best regards,
Stepan.

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-box yaf.net doesn't support SQL Azure.

Follow this detailed guide on how to [install yaf.net on Windows Azure](http://sergiikram.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/install-yaf-net-on-windows-azure-sql-azure-the-complete-guide/) in my blog.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the script files are not downloading correctly or something like that.  Have you looked at the html that gets downloaded to see if it looks correct?  Maybe compare your site to another YAF site to see what is missing.